# MongoDB Python вложенность

Tags: python, база-данных, json, mongodb, pymongo

Как работать с вложенностью в MongoDB в Python?

Имеется вот такая структура
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Извиняюсь за скрин, не умею вкладывать в текст JSON.

Как мне из MongoDB Python(pymongo) оперировать с объектами внутри этой структуры?
Как мне например через "_id" обратиться к "user_info" и из "user_info" обратиться к "items" и из "items" получить доступ к массиву, и данных в нем, по "item_type" ?

Как вообще оперировать с такими вложенными объектами?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

как то так:

```
result = db.main.find_one({'_id': 'ваш_id'})
items = list(filter(lambda item: item['item_type'] == 'socket', result['user_info']['items']))
```